# Fontawesome doesn't display accurately

Tags: font-awesome

Here is the screenshot of my 'icon-reorder' on Chrome.
[image: Screenshot of 'icon-reorder' on Chrome]

I can't figure out why it doesn't have the equal space between each bar.
I just use `<i class="icon-reorder"></i>` and that's it.

Do we have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: I just use `<i class="icon-reorder"></i>`

Comment: I found something after doing workaround.
`<i class="icon-reorder" style="font-size:15px"></i>`
I have to assign some bigger font size for it.
I think it may have a problem with small size icon.
But I still wonder why it displays accurately on fontawesome website without adding any font size.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not overwriting any of the `FontAwesome` defaults and you have defined the `font-size` before adding the fonts.

```
display: inline-block;
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: inherit;
font-size-adjust: none;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1;
text-rendering: auto;
```